# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 and symbol not found for architecture i386

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios7.1

I am developing a fake static framework. I build it and included it another sample application. The sample application is running fine on iPhone(ios 7.1), but it giving below errors when i run it on simulator

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/awsuser8/Desktop/Test.framework/Test, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Users/awsuser8/Desktop/Test.framework/Test
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Test", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: 1. If you have multiple library files from your libraries to include in the project you need to include the one for the simulator (i386) and the one for the device (armv7 for example). 2.  Make sure you add the correct libraries in the Link Binary With Libraries section of the Build Phases.

Answer (score 1):

You can rebuild the library for the iOS Simulator and combine it using lipo with the ARM build of the library.  Then the library will support x86 builds as well.